# How to properly get all the data base on date column current date using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem i don't think if this is a bug, why I can't get all the data base on the current date. I have here on my table column order_date where the customer order on the day. However I can't get the data based on my script, but **on my script I did is DATE(order_date)=CURDATE()**

**This is the order_date of customer today:**

[image: customer_order_date]

**This is the script that I have:**

[image: script]

```
    SELECT op.order_id,op.customer_id,customer_name,customer_number,op.or_number,delivery_status,
order_ship_address,delivery_status,order_date,amount,driver_firstname,transaction_number 
FROM order_properties as op 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id,order_id,amount,subtotal FROM payment) p 
ON op.order_id = p.order_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id,customer_name,customer_location,customer_number FROM customer_details) 
cd ON op.customer_id = cd.customer_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT driver_id,driver_firstname FROM driver) drive 
ON op.driver_id = drive.driver_id WHERE  DATE(order_date)=CURDATE()
```

As you see guys, there is no data that I get, but the order_date is today.

**Reference:**

[image: Order Date]

Comment: Are you sure the date comparison is the issue - I don't see that this portion of the code can fail.

Comment: I can't get the any data from that

Comment: I suggest you write a much simpler query to see if you get the order_dates you are looking for and if you find them start start adding the joins back in to see where the query fails. Or you could provide sample data as (text please).BTW I'm partially colour blind and cannot read the reference information provided.

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry for the image, i forgot..

Comment: What is the output of SELECT CURDATE()  ??

Comment: @Jervs here is '2019-06-10'

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have a timezone issue. As I read this, where I am, the current date is 2019-06-09, not 2019-06-10 (which is it in most of the rest of the inhabited world).

That might explain the discrepancy in your results.

I would also suggest that you write the logic as:

```
order_date >= CURDATE() and
order_date < CURDATE() + interval 1 day
```

This has nothing to do with the time zone issue, but it does allow the use of indexes.

Comment: it might guess timezone issue, because the customer order in canada which there time and date is 09/06/2019 then here in our country its 10/06/2019